# Characterizing finite non-abelian groups in which every subgroup is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How to prove: A non-abelian finite group in which every subgroup is abelian has order divisible by at most two primes.

Comment: Every proper subgroup, you mean.

Answer (score 2):

This is the first "General result" provided by G.A Miller and H.C Moreno in the following paper available [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1903-004-04/S0002-9947-1903-1500650-9/S0002-9947-1903-1500650-9.pdf)

Regards.