# Is there an easy criterion for a finite group, for which every proper subgroup is abelian?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Is there an easy criterion for a finite group for the property that every proper subgroup is abelian (not necessarily a normal subgroup) ?

It is clear that the abelian groups have this property, also the groups with order $p^3$ , $p$ a prime number because a proper subgroup has order $1$ , $p$ , or $p^2$, so it must be abelian. But what is the situation in general ?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin That seems to ask a very specific question about such groups, rather than ask for a classification.

Comment: Such group are called minimal nonabelian. The nilpotent ones are certainly classified (see for example the book by Berkovich), but I don't recall the general case.

Comment: This question is closely related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845254/characterizing-finite-non-abelian-groups-in-which-every-subgroup-is-abelian?rq=1

Comment: In the Miller and Moreno paper it is proved that either $G$ is a $p$-group with $|G'|=p$, or it is a semidirect product of a minimal normal $p$-subgroup with a cyclic $q$-group for distinct primes $p,q$. This is not a necessary and sufficient condition, but it usually gives enough information.